# Is this implementation of PBKDF2 correct?

Tags: hash, sha, hmac, pbkdf2

I am preparing for a presentation and I just want to double check that I've got it right:

PBKDF2 is:

```
for (0,4096)
{
     data1 = HMACSHA1(data1, data2); 
     data2 = HMACSHA1(data2, data1);
}
where data1 and data2 are pass and respectively salt and
HMACSHA1 = SHA1(salt+SHA1(pass+salt))
```

Is this correct?

Comment: 4096 iterations is only for the Kerberos standard, and WPA2. I removed your WPA2 tag as the question doesn't mention anything about it. If this *is* about WPA2, then the HMAC−SHA1 does make sense.

Comment: Yes, it is WPA2 related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong in two aspects.

1. The length of the DK is also important
2. The password is reused

According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) page (or you can go to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) if you'd like):

> `DK = PBKDF2(PRF, Password, Salt, c, dkLen)`

> where:

> - PRF is a pseudorandom function of two parameters with output length hLen (e.g. a keyed HMAC)
>
> ...

> Each hLen-bit block Ti of derived key DK, is computed as follows:

> `DK = T1 || T2 || ... || Tdklen/hlen`

> `Ti = F(Password, Salt, c, i)`

> `F(Password, Salt, c, i) = U1 ^ U2 ^ ... ^ Uc`

> where:

> `U1 = PRF(Password, Salt || INT_32_BE(i))`

> `U2 = PRF(Password, U1)`

> `...`

> `Uc = PRF(Password, Uc-1)`

WPA2 uses a 256 bits DK ( `DK = PBKDF2(HMAC−SHA1, passphrase, ssid, 4096, 256)`), so the process needs two blocks (`Ti`) to reach this since SHA1 is only 160 bits long. Furthermore, the iteration described here uses the original password for each iteration i.e. `Ui = PRF(Password, Ui-1)`, or you are reusing modified password on each iteration in your own loop.

For a simplified version for WPA2 I would write:

```
DK = B1 || trunc(B2)
B1 = F(Password, SSID || INT(1))
B2 = F(Password, SSID || INT(2))

where F(P, S) is the function

for(0, 4096) {
    U = HMAC-SHA1(P, S)
    S = U
}
```